# Oracle CAST MULTISET ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql, casting, associative-array

I'm trying to sort an Oracle PL/SQL collection (an associative array) using the approach presented [here](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/31/sorting-plsql-collections-the-quite-simple-way-part-two-have-the-sql-engine-do-the-heavy-lifting/). I modified the example from the linked page in order to use an **associative array**, but I guess I'm having some casting issues.

Here it is my code:

```
DECLARE

   TYPE TABLE_TYPE IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(10);
   table_in   TABLE_TYPE;
   table_out  TABLE_TYPE;

BEGIN

    -- 1. Populating the collection with random numbers between 1 and 50
    FOR i IN 1..9 LOOP

      SELECT ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50))
      INTO table_in('key-'||i)
      FROM DUAL;      

    END LOOP;

    -- 2. Trying to order the collection -> throws ORA-00902: invalid datatype
    SELECT CAST (MULTISET(
      SELECT * FROM TABLE(table_in)
      ORDER BY 2
      ) AS TABLE_TYPE
    )
    INTO table_out
    FROM DUAL;

END;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot use `MULTISET` on associative arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `associative array`  as a `table` in `select`, because that time is working `SQL Engine` and `SQL Engine` doesn't know what is `associative array`, `SQL Engine` can only works with `Table Type`, and you don't need first `select` (`select from dual`), you can do it via `pl/sql engine`, change it like this

```
....................
TYPE NumbersTableType IS TABLE OF NUMBER; -- it must be in global types, not in your local package
....................

DECLARE

   table_in   NumbersTableType := NumbersTableType();
   table_out  NumbersTableType;

BEGIN

    -- 1. Populating the collection with random numbers between 1 and 50
    FOR i IN 1..9 LOOP
      table_in.Extend;
      table_in(i):=ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50));
    END LOOP;

    SELECT CAST (MULTISET(
      SELECT * FROM TABLE(table_in)
      ORDER BY 1
      ) AS NumbersTableType
    )
    INTO table_out
    FROM DUAL;

END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Aside from the issue about the global scope (you are definitely right), is there a way to to use a global associative array indexed by a VARCHAR (as in my original code) instead of a numeric collection (as in your solution)?

Comment: NO, There should by only Table Type

Comment: @serkelion Since 12c it's possible to use table expression with the associative arrays defined in the package specification.

Comment: Thanks 0xdb. Unfortunately we're stuck with Oracle 11.2, so I had to use a Table type as workaround. I posted my trivial solution here, just in case other developers faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of completeness I'll report here the trivial workaround I used to order a collection (index by varchar) in Oracle version before 12c. The solution just replaces the associative array collection with a custom Table type (in order to make it visible to the SQL Engine).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_TABLE_TYPE_OBJ AS OBJECT (
  THE_KEY VARCHAR2(10),
  THE_VALUE NUMBER
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_TABLE_TYPE IS TABLE OF MY_TABLE_TYPE_OBJ;
/

DECLARE

   my_key VARCHAR2(10);
   table_in   MY_TABLE_TYPE := MY_TABLE_TYPE();
   table_out  MY_TABLE_TYPE := MY_TABLE_TYPE();

BEGIN

    -- Creating an unsorted collection
    FOR i IN 1..9 LOOP
      table_in.EXTEND;
      table_in(i) := MY_TABLE_TYPE_OBJ(
        'key-'||i,
         ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50))
      );
    END LOOP;

    -- Sorting the collection
    SELECT CAST (MULTISET(
      SELECT * FROM TABLE(table_in)
      ORDER BY 2
      ) AS MY_TABLE_TYPE
    )
    INTO table_out
    FROM DUAL;

END;
```

Hope this helps.